# How should I write this MySQL query containing multiple Left Joins

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I have a query consisting of multiple joins and I am wondering whether it can be re-written to improve performance.

I have 2 tables as follows (I have removed non-important columns for this example):

slots

```
------------------------------------------
| id   | name | slot_1 | slot_2 | slot_3 |
------------------------------------------
| 1    | Bob  | 1      | 2      | 3      |
| 2    | Jim  | 4      | 3      | 3      |
| 3    | Alf  | 1      | 2      | 5      |
------------------------------------------
```

(There are 25 slots in total, each in it's own column)

slot_details

```
-----------------------------------
| id   | stat_1 | stat_2 | stat_3 |
-----------------------------------
| 1    | 1      | 5      | 6      |
| 2    | 4      | 31     | 23     |
| 3    | 6      | 5      | 7      |
| 4    | 7      | 4      | 9      |
| 5    | 2      | 3      | 5      |
-----------------------------------
```

(There are 10 stats in total)

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT
    slots.name,
    slot_1_details.stat_1 AS slot_1_stat_1,
    slot_1_details.stat_2 AS slot_1_stat_2,
    slot_1_details.stat_3 AS slot_1_stat_3,
    slot_2_details.stat_1 AS slot_2_stat_1,
    slot_2_details.stat_2 AS slot_2_stat_2,
    slot_2_details.stat_3 AS slot_2_stat_3,
    slot_3_details.stat_1 AS slot_3_stat_1,
    slot_3_details.stat_2 AS slot_3_stat_2,
    slot_3_details.stat_3 AS slot_3_stat_3
FROM
    slots
LEFT JOIN
    slot_details AS slot_1_details
ON (
    slot_1_details.id = slots.slot_1
)
LEFT JOIN
    slot_details AS slot_2_details
ON (
    slot_2_details.id = slots.slot_2
)
LEFT JOIN
    slot_details AS slot_3_details
ON (
    slot_3_details.id = slots.slot_3
)
WHERE (
    slots.id = 1
)
```

The expected outcome of this query would be as follows:

```
| name | slot_1_stat_1 | slot_1_stat_2 | slot_1_stat_3 | slot_2_stat_1 | slot_2_stat_2 | slot_2_stat_3 | slot_3_stat_1 | slot_3_stat_2 | slot_3_stat_3 |
|bob   | 1             | 5             | 6             | 4             | 31            | 23            | 6             | 5             | 7             |
```

Unfortunately I am not in a situation where I can change the tables.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: I feel bad for you, that is a horrible design of those tables.

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
SELECT * FROM slots s LEFT JOIN slot_details sd ON s.id=sd.id
```

but i'm not sure because the query you posted is very confusing.

what are the keys of those tables?

Comment: The keys in both cases are the ID's.

I am trying to query the slots table to return a single row from a given id.

It also needs to return the 3 stats for each slot. Joining slot_details.id to slot.slot_1, slot.slot_2, slot.slot_3

I will add an example to the question.